# having some trouble with regex in as3

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, cpu

I want to extract from a string using regex, why doesn't it work?
From "10:13*12,20:23*22,60:36*432,...", i want to extract 10:13*12 then 20:23*22 and so on. Then, i want to extract from 10:13*12, 10, 13 and 12 and same with 20:23*22.

For example: levelObjs[i] = "10:13*12,20:23*22,60:36*432,..."

```
    var levelObjExp:RegExp = /(.*?),/ig;  
    var levelObjInfoExp:RegExp = /(\d+):(\d+)*(\d+)/ig;
    for(var i:int = 0; i < levelObjs.length; i++) {
    if(levelObjs[i] != 0){
        var levelObj:Object = levelObjExp.exec(levelObjs[i]);
        while (levelObj != null) {
            trace (levelObj[1]);
            var levelObjInfo:Object = levelObjInfoExp.exec(levelObj[1]);
            if (levelObjInfo != null) {
                var levelObjNum:int = levelObjInfo[1];
                var levelObjX:int = levelObjInfo[2];
                var levelObjY:int = levelObjInfo[3];
                trace(levelObjNum, levelObjX, levelObjY);
            }

            levelObj = levelObjExp.exec(levelObjs[i]);
        }
    }
```

}

Also, this code needs to be on every frame and it needs to be simple and with using less cpu usage as possible. Does regex uses relatively much cpu usage? Maybe is there a better way to do this without using regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe wrong RegExp.

fix following line

```
var levelObjInfoExp:RegExp = /(\d+):(\d+)*(\d+)/ig;
```

to

```
var levelObjInfoExp:RegExp = /(\d+):(\d+)\*(\d+)/i;
```